# Apache based site denied to everyone except but some IPs, with customised 403

Tags: apache

We need to have an IP protected Apache. So only a couple of IPs allowed for the whole server. Rest needs to be blocked. However, since all other IPs are blocked, even the custom error documents are blocked?! I've even chmoded these files to 777. My Directory code is below. Welcome any thoughts on how at least the `400.htm` and `404.htm` can be "allowed" for everyone so they can show up. Thanks.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/public
    ServerName xyz.com

    <Directory /opt/public>

            AllowOverride ALL              
            Require all granted
            Options -Indexes

            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
            Allow from 99.99.0.0/16
            Allow from 88.88.0.0/16

            ErrorDocument 403 /opt/public/400.htm
            ErrorDocument 404 /opt/public/404.htm

                <Files 400.htm>
                    <RequireAll>
                    Require all granted
                    Require not env blockAccess
                    </RequireAll>
                </Files>

                <Files ~ "404\.htm$">
                    <RequireAll>
                    Require all granted
                    Require not env blockAccess
                    </RequireAll>
                </Files>

     </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Two things. Do not change file permissions. Second, you are blocking by IP before allowing. See if moving the IP block below the allow error pages help. Be sure to stop and restart Apache before testing.

Comment: @closetnoc, good idea. But that didn't help. Anything else? Should I remove the `Files` blocks?

Comment: You are mixing old style and new style permissions.  You should not have `Order` and `Deny` mixed with `Require`.  See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#access

Comment: You are also requiring the environment variable `blockedAccess` to not be set to access those files.   I'm not sure what would set that variable or why you include that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /down.html
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
allow from 200.200.200.200
deny from all
</Limit>
```